# Android Studio: 'cannot access RecyclerView class file for android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView not found'

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, dependencies

I'm trying to make a simple to-do list app and have just importet this dependency

```
implementation 'it.xabaras.android:recyclerview-swipedecorator:1.2.3'
```

Now i get an error:

```
cannot access RecyclerView
class file for android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView not found
```

This is the method where i build the RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator

```
 @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull @NotNull Canvas c, @NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {


        new RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator.Builder(c,  recyclerView_NB, viewHolder_NB, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
                .addSwipeRightActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_delete_24)
                .addSwipeRightBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
                .addSwipeLeftActionIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_edit_24)
                .addSwipeLeftBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(adapter.getContext(), R.color.teal_700))
                .create()
                .decorate();

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
```

But the recyclerView_NB and viewHolder_NB(_NB just for clarification) is causing problems.

The tooltip is saying:

Provided type:

androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Required type:

android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Theese are the dependencies in gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'it.xabaras.android:recyclerview-swipedecorator:1.2.3'
```

What to do...

Comment: That library is for the old Android Support Library version of `RecyclerView`, and you are trying to use the modern AndroidX version of `RecyclerView`. You might want to consider other swipe libraries.

Comment: Cool. Thank you